# R3 Corda Integration/interoperability with Quorum -- other than JSON RPC

Tags: quorum, blockchain-interoperation

Am looking to integrate/interoperate Quorum with R3 Corda in a way that achieves atomicity e.g. 2 phase commit.

Understand that interledger focuses on interoperability and that could be a possibility.

Are there any other ways to integrate and inoperate the major blockchains?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you'd need a node that operates both and software to chat to both chains to achieve something like this. I'd  imagine this would all be somewhat custom depending on the use cases you are looking at.